# How do I get the VsDropdownBarClass instance for the current window?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mef, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk, visual-studio-package

I'm using MEF to write a Visual Studio extension using Visual Studio 2012 Pro. I would like to access the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.VsDropdownBarClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.vsdropdownbarclass.aspx) instance for the current window's dropdown bar.

Is this possible with Visual Studio extensions? The few dropdown bar examples I've found all deal with creating dropdown bars as part of a new language service rather than accessing a window's existing dropdown bar.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to display the same information (the types and members defined in the current file being edited) with a different UI. In an MVC sense, I want access to the dropdown bar's "model" so I can present it with a different "view."